# JQuery document.on and document.off for dynamically rendered elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap modal, with view comments and add comment functions. I'm trying to add comment by pressing enter, without having any visible button on my modal. The problem is since the button and textarea are rendered dynamically, I have to bind them to document and this is where i struggle. What is correct way of doing it? As i understood from official documentation, first I should specify events (keyup and click in my case), second selectors (ids of textarea and button) and then data and handler. I don't understand what are they in my case.

Html:

```
<textarea id="add-comment-textarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="add-comment-button" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;" tabindex="-1" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).off('keyup', '#add-comment-textarea');
$(document).on('keyup', '#add-comment-textarea', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log('key up');
        $('#addComment').click();
    }
});

$(document).off('click', '#add-comment-button');
$(document).on('click', '#add-comment-button', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to be `document`. It just needs to be a parent element that isn't replaced. Otherwise, assuming you aren't duplicating IDs, what you have seems about right.

Comment: It's worth noting that your form values won't submit or serialize, since they aren't [successful](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) (they're missing the `name` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the *events* with a simple whitespace in the *on* function. Furthermore, you have to write the selectors in *"* comma-separated. The last parameter of the *on* function is the origin handler assigned before to the events (cf. http://api.jquery.com/off/).

So you can use it like this:

```
$(document).off('click keyup', '#addComment, #add-comment-textarea');
$(document).on('click keyup', '#addComment, #add-comment-textarea', function() { /* Do something */ });
```

However, I am not sure that this does what you want. I would use the *off* function to unregister the events. Afterwards, I would register the events directly to the html elements:

```
$(document).off('click keyup', '#addComment, #add-comment-textarea');
$('#addComment').click(function() { /* Do something */ });
$('#add-comment-textarea').keyup(function(event) { /* Do something */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was solved after moving scripts to main View from modal partial.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete responses, take care to always reduce the root element to the closest of your target: if the comment elements are always docked in a accessible div, you could identify it, and then use $("#yourdiv").on(etc.) instead.